# Creating a power function in C# without using Math.Pow(x, y)

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and programing, for my first project I wanted to recreate the Math.Pow() function. My program works fine for int. Decimals I had to create a function to convert the decimal to fraction and had to write a squareroot function. However, the problem I am facing is if the fraction doesn't reduce to a smaller number then double is no longer able to handle it and program crashes. I can't use BigInteger because it doesn't support decimal values and there is no BigDecimal in C# as far as I am aware. I looked online for libraries for BigDecimal but they don't support multiplication. I am just wondering how would you handle large decimal values. FOR EXAMPLE 50 ^ 4.359 simplifies to 4359/1000 therefore, (50^(1/1000))^4359 this crashes the program.
My 3 functions:

```
        static double Exponent(double baseNum, double power)
        {
            double squared = 1;
            int n = (int)power;

            if (power == 0)
            {
                return squared;
            }
            else if (power == 1)
            {
                return baseNum;
            }
            else if (power % 2 == 0)
            {
                return Exponent(baseNum * baseNum, power / 2);
            }
            else if (power % 2 == 1)
            {
                return baseNum * Exponent(baseNum * baseNum, (power - 1) / 2);
            }
            return squared;
        }

        static double SquareRoot(double baseNum, double power)
        {
            // Assigns a random guess for the root.
            double root = 2;

            //The Newton Method for Computing Square Roots
            while (true)
            {
                root = root + (baseNum - Exponent(root, power)) / (power * Exponent(root, power - 1));
                if (Math.Round(Exponent(root, power), 6) == Math.Round(baseNum, 6)) break;
            }
            return root;
        }

        static double[] DecimalToFraction(double decimalValue)
        {
            // Converting decimal to fractions.
            double[] fraction = new double[2];
            // Assigns zi to decimal value.
            double zi = decimalValue;
            // Assigns Denominator value to zero this will be the previous value.
            double d0 = 0.0;
            // Assigns Denominator value to one this will be the current value.
            double di = 1.0;
            // Calculates the new Denominator value via the formula. 
            double dCurr = 1.0;
            // Numerator value initialized to zero to start.
            double ni = 0.0;
            // The accuracy required.
            double accuracyFactor = 0.000001;
            int count = 0;
            // Run loop until 15 iterations are reached or the accuracyFactor is reached.
            while(count < 15)
            {
                // Formula to get the current Z value.
                zi = 1 / (zi - (int)zi);
                // Formula to get the new Denominator Value.
                dCurr = di * (int)zi + d0;
                // Formula to get the new Numerator Value.
                ni = Math.Round(decimalValue * dCurr);
                // Assign current denominator to old denominator. 
                d0 = di;
                // Assign new denominator to current denominator.
                di = dCurr;
                count++;
                // Breaks function once accuracy is reached.
                if(Math.Abs(decimalValue - fraction[0]/fraction[1]) < accuracyFactor)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // Assign numerator value ni to fraction[0] and current denominator di to fraction[1]
                fraction[0] = ni;
                fraction[1] = di;
            }

            return fraction;

        }
```

Comment: Use `BigRational`. That works.

Comment: @Enigmativity There is no `BigRational` type in .NET's BCL, unfortunately (are you thinking of Java?).

Comment: @Dai - Sorry, you have to NuGet Microsoft's `BigRationalLibrary` to get it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don’t think BigRational has math functions. It’s useless for multiply numbers